# Не могу найти таблицу user в postgres

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, table

Накатываю миграции. Есть таблица `user`:

```
create table "user" (
    id serial not null,
    email text not null,
    password text not null,
    full_name text not null,
    password_reset_token text,
);
```

Захожу внутрь БД. А здесь совершенно другая схема:

```
my_user=# select * from user;
    user    
------------
 my_user
(1 row)
```

Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом контексте `user` является зарезервированной внутренней системной функцией `Postgres`, которая представляет текущего пользователя, вошедшего в базу данных (документация: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-info.html).

Этот запрос также может быть записан как:

```
SELECT user;
```

Также она является полным эквивалентом для [current_user](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-info.html)

---

В связи с этим лучше указывать схему, в которой находится таблица `user` или (если позволяет идеология проекта/компании/разработчика/др.) называть имена таблиц во множественном числе: `users`